# How to get an object from a List<typeObject> in a DropDownlistFor?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

As a beginner in c#/asp.net/mvc, I can't find how to get an object from a Html.DropDownList in the View.
Here is my ViewModel :

```
public class MyViewModel {
   public List<Something> ListOfSomething {get;set;} // A list of Somethings
   public Something TheSomethingToGet {get;set;} // The object I want to get
}
```

The "Something" object is for example :

```
public class Something {
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public int AnotherProperty {get;set;}
}
```

I populate my List<> in the controller :

```
public ActionResult Index () {
   MyViewModel mvm=new MyViewModel();
   mvm.ListOfSomething=(my code to populate the List);
   return View(vm);
}
```

The View is here :

```
@model Project.ViewModels.MyViewModel
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.ListOfSomething)
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ListOfSomething, new SelectList(Model.ListOfSomething, "id", "name"), "-")<br/>
```

And eventually, the [HttpPost] Index of the controller :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel mvm) {
    /* Here, how could I get the "Something" object that
       was selected in the dropdownlist and can be identified
       by the "id" property ?
    */

}
```

I'm totally wrong ?
Thanks

Comment: Something like `mvm.ListOfSomething.Where(o => o.Id == DropDownList.Selected.ID)` but the dropdownlist.selected.id part I am unsure of....

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding the `DropDownListFor` works with primitive types for example `int`, `string`, what you need to do is have the `SelectedId` property in the ViewModel and post that, then in controller using that Id you will have to pull the selected item from the collection in your view model in controller.

You can try it like:

```
public class MyViewModel {
   public List<Something> ListOfSomething {get;set;} // A list of Somethings
   public int SelectedItem {get;set;} 
}
```

and now in your view, you would have to do:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedItem, new SelectList(Model.ListOfSomething, "id", "name"), "-")
```

and then in your action method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel mvm) {
    // use mvm.SelectedItem id to get the selected complete object from repository
}
```

Hopefully it will help.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I understand now that the controller can't instantiate the Something object, it's my job to use the id to find and use the appropriate record or item of the List. Thanks